# Firing an event in a tray-icon app when an exe is launched?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to write a Tray-Icon application with WPF as a kind of add-on to a telephone software. However my only way of recieving data from said telephone software is by having it automatically execute a URI with parameters (command line or http). Essentially I can freely define the format similar to this:

```
trayapp.exe --num $caller.number --name $caller.name
```

When the telephone software recieves a call it'll automatically fill in the parameters and executes the target.

So basically I want a permanently active executable that's running in the background but my only way of getting the necessary info (like caller-number) is by passing it as a command line parameter.

Is there a good way to get the data that's being passed to a URI into my background application? It's not like I can just re-execute the tray-app, or can I? Communication via HTTP (locally!) seems overkill but I just don't know a windows-internal equivalent ...

Comment: A Window application has standard input and standard output.  So you the Net Library Process class create a memory stream in the app that is connected to standard input of the Process.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll consider it! What about defining a protocol, so you can define your own kind of URI, like for example spotify does (`spotify:track:6ovP7YhIM4PLapGXLYz4yS`)?

Comment: The dashed items are what is put into the parameter list.  The standard input can have commands just like a console input.  The console input is standard input.